# Shell-escape in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, gnuplot

This is a frequently asked question but none I have seen actually helped me. My problem is that I installed Gnuplot 5 and I have not been able to make it work in the TeXworks. The figure I have been trying to plot is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        title={Contour plot, view from top},
        view={0}{90}
    ]
    \addplot3[
        contour gnuplot={levels={0.8, 0.4, 0.2, -0.2}}
    ]
    {sin(deg(sqrt(x^2+y^2)))/sqrt(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As many answers have suggested I tried to call `gnuplottex` in the preamble with the code

```
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
```

yet this did not help and instead I have been getting the error

```
Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{.._contourmp0.table} could not be opened. See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation
```

followed by the warning that Shell escape is not enabled.

Could you please help me in making this work?

**EDIT** I am aware that there is a phenomenally identical question on this site, namely [gnuplottex with windows 8.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194623/gnuplottex-with-windows-8-1) but it does not address my problem. The problem persists even after using `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}`, as I pointed out from the beginning.

---

Following suggestions, I have made sure there is a path towards the `bin` directory and have included the statement `--enable-write18` in the PdfLaTeX command line of TeXworks. All other suggestions are of course welcome.

Also here is my attempt to compile through the command line:

[image]

And my Texmaker configuration:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [How to enable shell-escape in TeXworks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82699)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have but the version of TeXWorks discussed is a much older one and many settings have changed. I cannot quite follow it.

Comment: Huh? Looks exactly the same as the one I have, which according to Help -> About Texworks is version 0.5. Which version do you have, and how does the Preference-window look?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh dear, it's not TeXworks but Texmaker the one I am working with. Very sorry for the confusion. I amended the name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gnuplottex with windows 8.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194623/gnuplottex-with-windows-8-1)

Comment: @egreg It's not a duplicate, I have already tried what this post suggests and it does not work.

Comment: If the thing with the `PATH` variable worked, this question is a duplicate of [pgfplots contour example error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88947/35864).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have a MiKTeX distribution. Add the `--enable-write18` option to pdflatex options by opening the `Options` menu, `Configure TeXmaker` submenu. You'll get this pop-up window:

[image]

Comment: @JohnK It might just be me, and I have no tested it, but on my machine I have in the past successfully used `-enable-write18` with just one dash.

Comment: @JohnK You will have to locate the folder with `gnuplot.exe` in it (on my system that is `C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin`) and add that directory to the `PATH` variable, see http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path on how to do that.

Comment: @JohnK No, you will have to have something pointing to the `bin` directory. That might not solve the problem, though. I was just able to reproduce your issue on my computer. The problem seems to be that the file `<tksjs>_contourtmp0.table` is not created by the packages.

Comment: It should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnuplot\bin`.

Comment: @JohnK Have you tried running the compilation of the `.tex` file from the command line? Via `pdflatex -enable-write18 <filename without extension>`. If you have changed the PATH the old "have you tried turning it off and on again" trick might help. If all fails, please prepare a MWE and update your question.

Comment: @moewe Well, the command is accepted now and many lines of code are generated with some warnings though, for instance "You have requested the package ', but the package provides 'pgffor'".

Comment: @JohnK Aha! That is very interesting! Please show us the actual file you are running, but make sure it is a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) - you can add the file to your initial question. Also add the warnings and errors you get during compilation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22551/discussion-between-moewe-and-johnk).