# \mintinline expands to a single newline

Tags: formatting, texmaker, minted, code

I'm using Minted 2.1, that I have installed through `tlmgr`, and Texmaker 4.1. Compiling the following piece of code (straight from the documentation) :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
X\mintinline{python}{print(x**2)}X
\end{document}
```

... results in both X's on two consecutive lines, and nothing else (no error either).

However, compiling the same code from the terminal using the command-line from Texmaker's options window :

```
pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

... works as expected. How can I troubleshoot & solve this, so I can compile from Texmaker ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: your code processed with `pdflatex --shell-escape` produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y7TpE.png) without error in tl1025

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You made me think of trying it in a terminal rather than from Texmaker. And oddly enough, it works ! I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled with shell escape from TeXmaker?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just have to use TeXmaker's option dialog to change the compilation process to add the option `--shell-escape` to your default build setup (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/124577), following picture from same post, replace `-enable-write18` with `-shell-escape` if that doesn't work).

[image: Texmakers dialog]

As a word of warning: You should not compile all projects with shell escape enabled. Maybe you could try an alternative editor (like Texstudio, based on Texmaker), which enables you to specify custom toolchains.