# How to do shell escape?

Tags: standalone, shell-escape, png, convert

I read the answers and I'm not getting it. Some of them tell me to use preferences, others tell me to input

```
%!TEX option = --shell-escape
```

at the start.

Here's what my screen looks like, to show you that Idk where the Preferences tab is.
[image]

Basically want to convert that pic to png.

For efficiency in providing solutions, I'll provide the code in case there may be anything wrong with it:

```
\documentclass[convert=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\(\{P,Q\}\vdash R \)
\end{document}
```

It would be a great help to fix this. Thanks.

EDIT. Here's the result after adding the --enable-18 as requested.

[image]

Comment: Is this really a question about `shell-escape` or do you just not have `imagemagick` or `ghostscript`? You need one of those to do the conversion (see manual of `standalone`).

Comment: @TeXnician Oh. Sorry, I don't know what those are.

Comment: Then you are probably not failing with `shell-escape`. Please read the manual!

Comment: Sorry. Good point. Technically, I thought standalone was simple enough that reading the package would be unnecessary. I guess not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick answer utilizing [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/124577) post (following picture comes from it):

[image: tm shell escape]

You can just add `--enable-write18` (or `--shell-escape` respectively) to your `pdflatex` command.

Comment: Please check the edit. The conversion still failed.

Comment: @OsamaKawish Have you also tried `--shell-escape`?

Comment: Yes. I attempted both.