# Where should I put 'pdflatex -shell-escape <tex file>' code?

Tags: compiling

Im reading below document and trying do that:
[image]

But I dont know where to put below code:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape <tex file>
```

to active it. When I compiled only code inside this document, it showed me below error. Im using texlive to compile in windows.

[image]
That code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
A simple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt) ;.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Command_Prompt_on_Windows_10_Restone_%281607%29.png)

Comment: @Fran If the OP uses that OS, which we don't know. ?

Comment: How do you normally compile your LaTeX? All the instructions are telling you to do are to create a directory called `figures` and then run `pdflatex` as normal except with the addition of the `-shell-escape` command line parameter.

Comment: I dont really know how to use it. I cant compile normally with below code: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-4,0.)-- (4.,0.);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: I do not know what the problem may be for you; since the code compiles perfectly fine for me.

Comment: You need to put the code in the shell-escape, usually to be found in the settings tab. At least for me, it was set correctly already at the point of installation (TeXshop on mac, 2016 dist). There is a good chance that you don't have to add anything. Just put the `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize` at an appropriate place in the pre-amble. Note that if you want to put your figures into a subfolder, you _have to_ create that folder by hand.

Comment: @cfr  likelihood calculus: Most people use that OS and most users of that OS do not known what is the command prompt, and moreover seems strange a Linux user asking that.

Comment: @Fran But not at all strange an OS X user ask that.

Comment: @cfr, Yes, that user also exist . This is why it was a probability problem  `:)`

Comment: Please see my edit and show me what should I do to solve it. Thank for your help!

Comment: You still haven't told us whether you're using Windows, Mac or something else.

Comment: Im using texmaker and texlive in Windows 10!

Comment: Then @Fran is right. Follow the link.

Comment: If you want to configure TeXMaker to compile with shell-escape, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236641/shell-escape-in-texmaker).